# U-SQL extracting files complete contents (extracting full source code from html files)

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql, extractor

I've got a bunch of HTML files in my Data Lake Store and would like to get their full source code into a table (just one column with the code from all the files, the output format is not relevant to me, but probably tsv). I can't find a way to use the standard Extractors or anything on the web that works for me. Do I have to write a custom Extractor for that?

I've tried the Extractors.Tsv() and Extractors.Text() with a whole bunch of delimiters. I first tried:

```
@data =
EXTRACT source string
FROM "<MY DIRECTORY IN ADL>"
USING Extractors.Text(delimiter:'');
```

This didnt work out as it seems to not like having no delimiter, but also when I tried using delimiters that aren't in the html files it didnt work out.

Has anyone got an idea how to get this done? It seems to me that I am just stupid, so I hope someone here is a little smarter.

Even better than just the source code would be if I had the source code + filename in two columns, but I wanna start small.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this still a problem? See my comment to David's answer.

Answer (score 0):

@files =

```
EXTRACT FileName string,
        Text string
FROM @"/somepath/{FileName}.html"
USING Extractors.Text(silent: true, delimiter: '`');
```

`OUTPUT @files
TO "/somepath/Test.txt"
USING Outputters.Tsv(outputHeader: false, quoting: false);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried this but still get an error (which is the same one I got before as well):

Error occured while extracting row after processing 722 record(s) in the vertex' input split. Column index: 0, column name: 'Text'.

Vertex failed with a fail-fast error

Have you by any chance got an idea why this happens?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You probably have some format error (value that cannot be parsed because too large, too many columns etc). Normally an inner error message should show that, but in the Oct timeframe, that inner error was not shown. I hope that you were able to figure out what caused the error.